# How do I call more than one web API from a web app (Azure B2C)

Tags: .net, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I've been following the tutorial here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-dotnet-webapp-and-webapi and have managed to get a web app authenticating with Azure B2C.  I have also managed to get the web app to call ONE web API as instructed in the template.

My question is how do you call more than one API using this method?  I may have 4-5 web API's set up as in the example and want to call all of them from a single web app.  Is this possible?  If so are there any examples I can take a look at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to get a refresh_token after the authorization is finished.

Use this refresh_token to exchange another access_token with the scope of another web application. Like this:

[image]

Then we can get an access_token for another scope:

[image]

See details from [Refresh the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token).

BTW, [OBO flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow) seems to work for you as well. It allows an application to invoke a service/web API, which in turn needs to call another service/web API.

Comment: Thanks.  I believe the method you have provided above though is for API to API calls.  I want to be able to call 2 API's from the same web application.  Is the process the same for this example or should I be looking somewhere else?

Comment: @Jason OBO flow is for  API to API calls. But the refresh token method is for calling different API's from the same web application.

Comment: Can you point me to any examples of this being done. I'm struggling to understand how to get the refresh_token in the first place to then pass this on.

Comment: @Jason  Sorry for the delay. I just came to office. Have you learned about authorization code flow? It will return the refresh token: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-access-token.